# Resizing a numpy array without padding

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, resize, reshape

I have a set of data that I'm using `numpy.loadtxt` to read in 3 specific columns, with the number of rows being flexible. I want to write the data to a new file with a new shape i.e. 9 columns, but I just want this new shape to be filled sequentially with the original data, so original rows 0, 1 and 2 would go to the new row 0... original rows 3, 4 and 5 to the new row 1 and so on.

For my test file using `x.reshape(-1, 9)` did the trick, but I happened to have the right amount of data points to fill the new array. If I try with original data that has a number of rows that is not divisible by 9 I get the following error...

`ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 34149 into shape (9)`

My solution was to use `np.reshape(x, (1, -1)` then calculate the number of rows and use `np.resize(x, (num_rows, 9))` but it pads the last row with data from the start - I need a solution that just puts nothing in the final row where there is no data

Thanks

Comment: A problem with "nothing" is that it can't be formatted with the same `fmt` that handled the other data (assuming it's numeric).  Also how do you propose loading this new csv with (possibly) irregular rows?

Answer (score 0):

Consider this dummy data:

```py
>> x = np.random.randint(0,10,(4,3))
>> x

array([[0, 3, 9],
       [1, 9, 7],
       [2, 9, 6],
       [7, 4, 3]])
```

If I understand correctly, you'd like to pad it with 2 rows of `np.nan` *before* you `.reshape((-1,9))` it. Why 2 extra rows in this example? Because that's the smaller number to add to the length of `x` so it becomes a multiple of `3` (thus making the overall number of entries divisible by `9`).

In general, you'd like to add `(3-len(x)%3)%3` rows to `x` (don't get frightened by the calculation, feel free to replace it with something more readable, that ensures that the eventual number of entries is divisible by 9).

So all in all, if I understand correctly, a one-liner solution for your problem is:

```py
>> np.r_[x, np.full(((3-len(x)%3)%3,3),np.nan)].reshape((-1,9))

array([[ 0.,  3.,  9.,  1.,  9.,  7.,  2.,  9.,  6.],
       [ 7.,  4.,  3., nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]])
```

More explanations:

- the `np.full((something,3), np.nan)` generates an ndarray [full](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.full.html) with `np.nan` values (of course, fell free to replace `np.nan` with whatever you consider as *"nothing"*);
- it is then appended to your original array `x`, using [`numpy.r_`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html);
- and eventually [reshaped](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) per your request to `(-1,9)`.

Comment: This works great except I now get `nan` written where before I had the repeated data. I think this is because I am reading the data in as str and writing it as str. And the reason I'm doing that is that it was the only way I could get it to write my data exactly as it was read in terms of decimal places (i.e. I wanted 0 written as 0, something with 3 decimal places written with 3 decimal places, 2 dp written with 2 dp etc.). I should point out that I am extreme novice so I understand this may not have been the best solution!

Comment: I'm still not sure what you *want* to achieve. By the way, that's why it's always recommended to include in your original question some example code, example input, as well as example "expected result".

So what *do* you want the result to be? How will those extra cells in the numpy array be filled? (e.g. the last 6 cells in my example that currently have `np.nan` in them)

Comment: I just read your edited response, so perhaps I confused matters with the decimal place issue. I replaced `np.nan` with `""`, which works to an extent, but then I still have spaces where I just want nothing...this may or may not be an issue for the new file, I'm not sure yet!

Comment: @sbeercan, correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe you're dealing with several topics at the same time: (1) how to quickly pad the array and reshape it (what I believed was the main topic of this question). (2) formatting the output of numpy arrays. (3) holding several data types in the same array?...

=> please consider again the last 6 cells in my example that currently have `np.nan` in them - **what would you like the computer's memory to hold in those cells?**

Comment: Essentially I have data in a conventional form, 3 columns (it is x, y, z data), and I want convert into a new form that is saved as a file to be read by in imaging software. But the new form is odd....it is basically 9 data points on each line filled row by row (i.e.  x0, y0, z0, x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2 where the number is the index of the original row), when it gets to the end I don't want extra data in any form filling up the last spaces, i just want it to stop with the final data point

Comment: so from your last comment, possibly numpy is not suitable for exactly what I'm after

Comment: @sbeercan, maybe this will clarify some things: the arrays we've both been using are **dense**, in the sense that they contain values in **ALL** of their cells. When you say that you want the array to have "nothing" in some cells - it's just your human way of thinking about it. You still have to decide how "nothing" is represented in the computer's memory. A common choice is `np.nan`. A more confusing choice can be `0`, or the empty string `""` etc.

Comment: I feel that the question has diverted from *reshaping* arrays to *printing* or *formatting* content. If you just want to print all rows in `x` except for the last one, consider `x[:-1]` or `x[:-1,:]` and then a special care of the last row if necessary? (i.e. if the number of cells is not a multiple of 9? note that you do not need anything like `np.reshape(x, (1, -1))` that you mentioned in your question, but can easily use `len(x)` to determine that in your case)

Comment: I apologise for not explaining my self very clearly and I appreciate your patience! In the output file (its just a .txt file) I basically want the x, y, z data instead of stacked on top of each other (as in a standard table with 3 columns), to be placed side by side but with only 9 data points (i.e. 3 rows of the original data) per line. So depending how many rows in my original data set, the last line of the new file will have 3, 6 or 9 data points, but if its 3 or 6 I don't want additional characters on that line

Comment: Ok. This indeed diverts from the original title of "Resizing a numpy array", and it seems like you're merely interested in **printing** the result and not in how it's **stored** in memory or whether or not it is padded. If that's the case, then see my previous comment above -- namely, if `len(x)%3 != 0`, then maybe simply print `x[:-1]` (x except its last row) in a certain manner, and the treat differently its last row? (even a simple for loop on that row will suffice)

Comment: Forgive me, I'm not sure how this ensures I have 9 data points, then a new line, then 9 data points etc... in my new file. I'm using `np.savetxt` to write the new file so in my mind the data needs to be read in and manipulated, then written to the new file by passing as X (`numpy.savetxt(fname, X, fmt...etc`)

Comment: Do you *have to* use `np.savetxt` for some reason? If so, then do something like ```with open("out.txt", "a") as f: np.savetxt(f, x, ...); f.write(the last line);```

-- in any case, this has long diverted from the original topic of resizing an array. If the matter or resizing an array was resolved, and the remaining problem is printing / saving to file / using `np.savetxt` and issues related to it, then consider narrowing the problem down, writing your (new!) question in a concise manner, and adding an example input and expected output. It will gain more traction.

Comment: No, only that I am very new to this and working it out as I go along. With the help you have given I should be able to move forward...very much appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

A simple and fast way of filling an array with padding use the `flat` iterator:

```
In [180]: arr = np.arange(1,13).reshape(3,4)
In [181]: arr
Out[181]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12]])
In [182]: res = np.zeros((3,5),int)
In [183]: res.flat[:arr.size] = arr
In [184]: res
Out[184]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [11, 12,  0,  0,  0]])
```

Obviously the 'padding' depends on what we initially put in `res`.  For numeric data, 0 and 1 are easiest.  Other values are possible, such as `nan` for floats, or `''` for string entries.

```
In [191]: res = np.zeros((3,5),'U10')
In [192]: res
Out[192]: 
array([['', '', '', '', ''],
       ['', '', '', '', ''],
       ['', '', '', '', '']], dtype='<U10')
In [193]: res.flat[:arr.size] = arr
In [194]: res
Out[194]: 
array([['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
       ['6', '7', '8', '9', '10'],
       ['11', '12', '', '', '']], dtype='<U10')
```

But how do you expect to write this array to a file?  `savetxt` expects to work with rows of consistent size and dtype.  A `%s` `fmt` will write anything, but you loose most formatting and alignment control.

This last doesn't look too bad as csv:

```
In [195]: np.savetxt('test', res, delimiter=',', fmt='%10s')
In [196]: cat test
         1,         2,         3,         4,         5
         6,         7,         8,         9,        10
        11,        12,          ,          ,
```

It can even be loaded:

```
In [199]: np.loadtxt('test', dtype='str', delimiter=',')
Out[199]: 
array([['         1', '         2', '         3', '         4',
        '         5'],
       ['         6', '         7', '         8', '         9',
        '        10'],
       ['        11', '        12', '          ', '          ',
        '          ']], dtype='<U10')

In [201]: np.genfromtxt('test', dtype=float, delimiter=',')
Out[201]: 
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.],
       [ 6.,  7.,  8.,  9., 10.],
       [11., 12., nan, nan, nan]])
```